# Getting rid of a new line when using console.log in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, console, output, newline

I'm trying to run this function in a learning environment, but it results in an error of "Your program's output is longer than expected" because console.log produces a newline by default. Are there any ways I can fix this?

```
function calcSquare() {
    x = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    result = x**2
    console.log("The square of", parseInt(x), "is", parseInt(result))
}
```

Comment: What environment is this specifically? What `console.log` does, and how to print differently, varies greatly.

Comment: @Bergi it's Viope

Comment: Hm, I can't find any documentation about how they execute code. I'd suggest to ask your teacher, or Viope support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in node, you can use `process.stdout.write("foo");`. You can call this multiple times without breaking into a new line.

```
process.stdout.write('foo');
process.stdout.write('bar');
```

Ouputs:
`foobar`